# Image > duplicate equivalent in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have an open .AI file that I want to make changes to, but I want to keep the original as well. If I was on Photoshop I would simply go to the <kbd>Image</kbd> menu and click <kbd>Duplicate</kbd>, and I would get an (unsaved) duplicate copy of the file.  Is there an Illustrator equivalent to this, or do I have to <kbd>Save As...</kbd> and then open the new file?

Just seems a bit strange that this simple feature hasn't found its way from Ps to Ai...

I'm using both CS6 (on Mac) and CC (on Windows)

Answer (score 2):

Well, my way of doing this is by creating a second artboard in the same file and copy/paste the design from the first artboard to the second one and work on the second artboard. As simple as that.

Hope it will work for you too and helps your workflow.

> PS: Also, in **PS** if you use **Duplicate**, you still have to save it as a
>   different file. so...yeah, the difference between using Duplicate
>   function and <kbd>Shift+Crtl+S</kbd> (Save as) is about 1/2 second...

Comment: The advantage I find of Duplicate vs Save As is that I can duplicate a file five times, make different edits to each one, and then decide which one I like, without creating piles of files that i'm then just going to delete.

Comment: @ChristyJames The same thing you can do with artboards...you can create as many as you wand and have them in the same document and you also can compare them without having to move from one document to another. I looked into in and this seams to be the best way of doing it. Also, another one would be to place your design inside a parent layer and duplicate that layer + hide the others but it's a bit messy.

Comment: @ChristyJames Select the Artboard tool and Alt drag the artboard to make a copy.

Answer (score 0):

Using art boards is the best way to work with variations but if that doesn't work for you simply select your artwork and hit `ENTER`.

You'll see the **Move** dialogue box appear where you can set a new position. Press `Copy` and WHA LAH! a second copy of your graphic(s) without a saved version of your file.

Answer (score 0):

On my apple, I save the file to a folder. Open the folder, highlight the image and utilize the duplicate command in the "Socket" drop down menu.

Answer (score 0):

- Select All (<kbd>CommandCtrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>)
- Edit > Copy (<kbd>CommandCtrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>)
- File > New (<kbd>CommandCtrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>)
- <kbd>Enter</kbd> or<kbd>Return</kbd>
- Edit > Paste (<kbd>CommandCtrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>)

Using shortcuts, this is actually *faster* than the duplicate command in Photoshop.

Comment: If you had artboards or other assets they wouldnt come along. You can easily do this with a line of javascript though